# ManyToMany relation use in service

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Job entity

```
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_job",
        joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "job_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    )
    private List<User> user;
```

User entity

```
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_job",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

Role entity

```
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;
```

Here we have a table user_job with 3 ids and I want to insert data in service layer. How I can do it and what repository I should implement or use existent like user/role/job?

```
class UserJobService{
public void setUserJob(User user, Job job, Role role){

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `@ManyToMany` association is you can't delete a record directly from `user_job` table, using Hibernate. To delete the record, you need to load a user with all his jobs. So better to add `UserJobEntity`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_JOBS")
class UserJobEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID")
    private Job job;

}

public UserJobEntity createUserJob(UserEntity user, JobEntity job) {
    UserJobEntity userJob = new UserJobEntity();

    userJob.setUser(user);
    userJob.setJob(job);

    return userJobRepository.save(userJob);
}
```

Probably you will want to add (user, job) unique constraint to `user_jobs` table.

**Some advices**

1. Use plurals for table names. `user_jobs` in place of `user_job`
2. `Role` is tabular data. So it shouldn't have a users `List`.
3. Don't use `Set` for associated collections. Definitely you will encounter  "multiple bugs fetch exception" and this exception will help you to change queries. With `Set` you can have large cross products and even don't notice them.